# Multithreading requests with queue cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, pthreads

Im trying to make multithreaded proxy checker in c++, when I start the threads and lock it all threads wait till the request is finished. I tried to remove the locks but that doesn't help either. Im using the cpr library to make the requests, the documentation can be found here: https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/advanced-usage.html.

Reproduceable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>

#define NUMT 10

using namespace std; 
using namespace fmt;

std::mutex mut;
std::queue<std::string> q;

void* Checker(void* arg) {

    while (!q.empty()) {

        mut.lock();

        //get a webhook at https://webhook.site

        string protocol = "socks4";
        string proxyformatted = format("{0}://{1}", protocol, q.front());
        
        auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ "<webhook url>" },
            cpr::Proxies{ {"http", proxyformatted}, {"https", proxyformatted} });

        q.pop();
        mut.unlock();
    }

    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    q.push("138.201.134.206:5678");
    q.push("185.113.7.87:5678");
    q.push("5.9.16.126:5678");
    q.push("88.146.196.181:4153");

    pthread_t tid[NUMT]; int i;
    int thread_args[NUMT];


    for (i = 0; i < NUMT; i++) {
        thread_args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, Checker, (void*) &thread_args);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUMT; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d terminated\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting that you've mixed `std::mutex` and pthreads. Is there a reason you didn't use `std::thread`?

Comment: Haven't tried `std::thread`, I'll give it a try thanks.

Comment: Undefined behavior for non-readonly, non-atomic, unsynchronized access to an object from multiple threads.

Comment: Using `std::thread` won't change a thing. I can be confident of that even though I don't know what your problem is. You need to clearly state what is going wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 Im trying to make multithreaded requests to validate proxies, Im using a queue to load proxies from a proxy-list. Im a begginer in c++, sorry if I made it hard explaining my issue.

Comment: Describe the behaviour you expect to see and the behaviour that you are seeing. By your own admission the code doesn't work, and if the only description of the required behaviour is the code we have nothing to work from other than to state generalities like EOF's point about `q.empty()` not being protected by the mutex.

Comment: Think on what you are trying to do. If the mutex remains locked for the entire transaction, multiple threads are worthless. Only one thread can operate on the queue at a time. Consider popping a job from the queue while working on it, unlocking the mutex, working on the item, and then locking the mutex to put the item back if the job fails. This will allow multiple threads to work simultaneously.\

Comment: @user4581301 Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to implement a wrapper class for your queue that will hide the mutex.

That class can provide `push(std::string s)` and `bool pop(std::string& s)` that returns `true` and populate `s` if the queue wasn't empty or false othervise. Then your worker threads can simply loop

```
std::string s;    
while(q.pop(s)) {
...
}
```

Comment: I recommend completing the answer with an `if (failed) { q.push(s) }`.

Comment: @user4581301 sounds good, but in original question `q.pop();` is called unconditionally

Comment: I stand down on my objection. I misread the description of the question and assumed the asker had left that detail out in the code. Probably my brain inserting extra requirements because the only reason I can think of for not immediately popping is wanting to leave the item in the queue so it can be repeated in the event of failure. Kinda glad I didn't answer now.